# QGIS Vector Layers not showing up?

Tags: qgis, vector-layer

I'm IT dept for a company and we've been roped into helping with this issue but we have no actual knowledge of the workings of QGIS outside of installing it...

We have one user who can open QGIS projects and when they open IDW Interpolation the 'Vector Layer' has a bunch of options That are taken from this CSV file.
[image]

But when this other user opens that same file and IDW Interpolation the only option under Vector Layer is the name of the File itself not the other columns from this CSV file?
[image]

Now I'm told by this user that the options on that list should come from a CSV file, I tried going to layer > Add vector Layer and adding the CSV it should be getting the data from but that only adds one other Table option to the list not all the individual columns that should be showing up.

Could someone point a direction we can start looking?

Comment: Hi, To add a csv layer you need to use the Add Delimited Text Layer instead of Add Vector Layer. In your first screenshot, that long list of option is coming from the Interpolation attribute dropdown, not the Vector layer parameter dropdown. The Vector layer dropdown will contain all vector layers in the current project. The Interpolation attribute dropdown contains the list of all numeric fields from the currently selected vector layer which can be used for interpolation. Essentially, they are drill-down combo boxes- the Vector layer is the parent and Interpolation attribute is dependant.

Comment: You can refer to [Importing a delimited text file](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/managing_data_source/opening_data.html#importing-a-delimited-text-file) help page on how t do that.

Comment: Thanks Guys, thats been great help

Comment: and in case it matters, from the 2 screenshots, it is not the same file